# RMarkdown parameters - how to document (--help)?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Parametrized reports in `rmarkdown` are great, however, how to document the parameters? It is very easy to reach a point when the there 10 different parameters and it becomes hard to decipher what which one means.

In an `Rscript` one could use `argparser` to add arguments with a small description and it becomes self documenting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(argparser, quietly=TRUE)

# Create a parser
p <- arg_parser("Round a floating point number")

# Add command line arguments
p <- add_argument(p, "number", help="number to round", type="numeric")
p <- add_argument(p, "--digits", help="number of decimal places", default=0)

# Parse the command line arguments
argv <- parse_args(p)

# Do work based on the passed arguments
cat( round(argv$number, argv$digits), "\n")
```

In `rmarkdown` this does not seem possible:

```
---
title: "Round numbers"
output:
  html_document
    code_folding: hide
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
author: "`r Sys.info()['user']`"
params:
  number: NA
  digits: 0

---
```

How to add `help` to a parametized report? (bonus for optional and required arguments)

Comment: Could you just use R comment syntax to add comments along your code documenting it as it goes?

Comment: I could, but I was looking for a more elegant solution such as calling `rmarkdown::render, ..., params = list(help))` and get printed help. I guess that for now I will got with your suggestion.